# Setup Vercel CLI to work with a staging environememt

Tags: circleci, vercel

I'm trying to get Vercel to work with our CircleCI pipeline (we want to run tests beforehand). We WANT to have 2 environments:

- stagging - on commits to `main` we want to have the changing reflected on our staging env
- prod - on commits to `prod` we want to update our prod env

Ideally, these deployments should be triggered by our CircleCI pipeline only.
Is this possible to do with Vercel CLI? We want to have a custom domain for our staging env (e.g. `myApp-staging.vercel.app`). I saw there was a tutorial on how to setup Vercel with Github Actions, but it doesn't really go into setting up staging and prod.

I know there is the concept of preview environments in Vercel. That feels slightly off to me, however... We want to have only 1 prod env and only 1 staging env.

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Vercel CLI
        run: npm install --global vercel@latest
      - name: Pull Vercel Environment Information
        run: vercel pull --yes --environment=production --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
      - name: Build Project Artifacts
        run: vercel build --prod --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
      - name: Deploy Project Artifacts to Vercel
        run: vercel deploy --prebuilt --prod --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
```